# Is there any way out so that a video available online cannot be downloaded?

Tags: video, download, streaming

Is there any way out so that a video available online cannot be downloaded ? I have checked almost every way out and found that everything can be spoofed. So does anyone knows anything else that cannot be spoofed ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to understand that in order for the human user to *view* the content, the browser (or some other software) need to download it.  And when the content has been downloaded to the user's computer, *you* no longer control the access to it.

So-called "streaming" is just a download-mode where the *standard* viewer is programmed to automatically delete the content after it has been viewed by the human.  However, this can be circumvented by either using a non-standard viewer (i.e. one that skips the deletion step), or by having another piece of software running that grabs the content from the frame buffer *when* it being viewed - and saves it permanently.

If it can be viewed, it can be captured.

Comment: Another characteristic of streaming is that the content typically begins to be viewed *before* it is completely downloaded. (Doesn't change the answer here, but you might want to add that to present a clearer picture of streaming.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for absolute security, then no. Everything that can be seen can be downloaded. You can just make it harder. Screengrabbing will *always* work.

Answer (score 1):

Not if someone really wants the content, no.

But to defeat casual users, you can try the following:

1. host your video on amazon s3 + cloudfront
2. use signed urls so the url can only be requested from a certain ip for a certain amount of time
3. keep the signed url generating page (say php) behind a login, and only let them login from a certain number of ip addresses per month

if they have [stream capturing software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtmpdump), then you are out of luck, but they can't share the login with too many people, and they can't share the video url with anyone.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Streaming